# Spring Hibernate SessionFactory- without mapping table to classes

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am having a problem setting up SessionFactory in my application. In dispatcher-servlet.xml I have written

```
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />

    </bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />     
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

In my java class I have done something like

```
@Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

 public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}


public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}


private Session openSession()
{       
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}
```

My application when running always gives NullPointerException on  method  openSession().

Please note that I am not using any Annotated DAOs. I am trying to directly connect with database table without having Pojos for each table and trying to implement Native Queries instead of HQL.  Is it possible to do?

Comment: yes, it is possible... but you need to define an annotation for this class where you open the session...  something like @Service

Comment: Sorry mate.. it didn't help out.. I kept @Service .. but still NullPointerException

Comment: Are you creating the the spring context, something like this: `ApplicationContext context = 
       new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"dispatcher-servlet.xml"});`?

Comment: In web.xml file     

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

Answer (score 0):

You should mark somehow the class that contains the sessionfactory (e.g.: @service)

In any case you are using hibernate in the wrong way: hibernate is great because it manages the sql execution for you, it makes db interaction easy. If you use only native query, without any pojo, then hibernate is useless. I tell you more: in this case hibernate is even bad, it creates wasted data structure that you never use. Hibernate is great but of course is not light.

My suggestion is: use spring jdbc template.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I totally understand your points. But isn't there any way to do this ? I used @Service  in class where SessionFactory is called.. but still SessionFactory is null. I tried with Respository too but same issue.

Comment: change the org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean to org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean

Comment: Yup done.. but sessionFactory is still null. I can't execute any queries.

Comment: Ok, we need to go deeper: did you define the servlet in web.xml? Like this:
  
    <servlet>  
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>  
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>  
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
    </servlet>

Comment: Yes, this is included in web.xml

<servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

Answer (score 0):

1- Add Transaction Support-

```
            <bean id="transactionManager"    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
                 <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
            </bean>
```

2- Enabling transactional support

```
  <tx:annotation-driven/>
```

3-Make your class Transactional

```
         @Transactional
```

Comment: It would be good to include actual details on how to do this.